# Do these graphs have names?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm working with finite, directed graphs equipped with a supplementary structure, consisting in a cyclic order on the edges meeting at a given vertex. This kind of graph seems ubiquitous when doing planar graphs. I haven't found relevant information on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory) regarding a name for their species, hence my question:

Is there a name for this kind of graphs?

[image]

If it helps, in addition the graphs I'm concerned with only have sinks or sources (all edges meeting at a given vertex either all arrive at or all depart from it).

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "cyclic order on the edges meeting at a given vertex."

Comment: I mean that an ordered labelling is imposed on the edges near the vertex (and I expect a planar  geometrical realization to be compatible with this ordering in the obvious way). I'll put a picture asap.

Comment: Looks like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_system - which, confusingly is a pair of permutations. You can convert between the cyclic edge order and the flag permutations quite easily

Comment: @gilleain: I was aware of the equivalent formulation with pairs of permutations, but didn't know the name. Thank you for the reference! If you'd care to post this as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cyclic ordering of edges that defines the [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) of the graph is called a [rotation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_system) although I have also seen the terminology "[planar constellation](http://www.dmtcs.org/pdfpapers/dm060102.pdf)" - this seems to be a generalization.

A clearer explanation is on the page for [combinatorial map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_map)